# Zakat to a person knowingly doing zina

Tags: zakat, sadaqah-al-fitr

a brother of mine has been living with a woman (probably non-muslim, not sure) without doing nikah for some time. They even have baby now. After repeatedly advising, they did not do nikkah. He is poor, is it permissible to give him zakat or sadaqah?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allah the Almighty said:

> Zakah expenditures are only for **the poor** and for **the needy** and for **those employed to collect** [zakah] and for **bringing hearts together** [for Islam] and for **freeing captives** [or slaves] and for **those in debt** and for **the cause of Allah** and for **the** [stranded] **traveler** - an obligation [imposed] by Allah . And Allah is Knowing and Wise. ([9:60](https://legacy.quran.com/9/60))

I can't find here a prohibition to give it a person committing adultury or any sin, or can you?
In fact wouldn't it bring their hearts together and turn them back to Islam and maybe remind them of Allah, their religion and repentance?

Comment: Great point, dear brother. We have been reminding them about the severity of the sins they are doing, and about repending back and correcting the wrong. But nothing really bother them as such. Also, just having a muslim name would not be enough to be eligible would it?

Answer (score 0):

Brother, in my very humble opinion, the most important point is to really see what are the teachings for you. Zakat is fard on you and to see who you are paying as brother @Medi1Saif has said deserving ones have been clearly mentioned in the Quran and the point about winning their heart through this is such a beautiful point.

People's deeds are their personal actions. You are doing your part by preaching to them what's good and bad. Now just imagine would letting someone die just because they are a sinner be acceptable.

Islam teaches to hate the evil, not the human committing it. The way I see it they are spiritually weak and diseased and probably need more of our attention, prayers, and help to bring them back.